# Não sei onde estou errando na criação do store procedure

Tags: mysql

Alguem me ajuda?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE 'sp_pessoas_insert' (  pessoa INT(11),
    name VARCHAR(20),
    lastname VARCHAR(55), 
    age CHARACTER(2),
    genre boolean,
    countrie CHARACTER(2),
    state INT(11),
    city INT(11),
    income CHARACTER(8),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    password VARCHAR(100) ) BEGIN

    INSERT INTO person VALUES(pessoa, name, lastname, age, genre, countrie, state, city, income, email, password)

    SELECT * FROM person WHERE id =  LAST_INSERT_ID();
     END
```

Me retorna o erro:
[image: ERRO AO CRIAR PROCEDURE]

Já vasculhei em tudo e não consigo resolver este problema ao criar a procedure, podem me ajudar e explicar se for possível oque está ocorrendo?!

Comment: Essas aspas simples no nome da procedure existem na sintaxe do SQL?

Comment: como o @AndersonCarlosWoss observou deve ser esse o problema, no `mysql` se usa a crase no lugar das aspas simples para nomes

Comment: Obrigado a todos voces que reservaram um tempo pra me ajudar. realmente o erro era as aspas simples, estou começando a  mexer com procedures e também sou novo aqui no stack, quero ate pedir ajuda de como avaliar a resposta de vocês.

Answer (score 3):

O erro, como apontado nos comentários é que você está utilizando aspas simples `( ' )` no lugar do apóstrofe ( ` ) para o identificar o nome da procedure.

Outra coisa que não é um erro, mas é uma [sintaxe de será descontinuada](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=13127) é o `integer display width` (aqueles números entre parêntesis de pois do INT). Você não precisa deles.

Segue uma versão modificada da procedure compilando no mysql 8.

```sql
DELIMITER $$

CREATE  PROCEDURE `sp_pessoas_insert` (  
    pessoa INT,
    name VARCHAR(20),
    lastname VARCHAR(55), 
    age CHARACTER(2),
    genre boolean,
    countrie CHARACTER(2),
    state INT,
    city INT,
    income CHARACTER(8),
    email VARCHAR(100),
    password VARCHAR(100) ) 
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO person VALUES(pessoa, name, lastname, age, genre, countrie, state, city, income, email, password);
    SELECT * FROM person WHERE id = LAST_INSERT_ID();
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Vlw de novo fabiano vou avaliar a resposta, e se não for pedir muito como posso marcar a questão como resolvida?

Comment: Claro! Valeu. 
:)